# JeroMQ Subscriber in a Runnable

Tags: multithreading, scala, zeromq, jeromq

I'm trying to embed ZMQ subscriber in a Runnable.
I'm able to start the Runnable for the first time and everything seems okay.
The problem is when I interrupt the Thread and try to start a new Thread, the subscriber does not get any messages. For example:

1. I have a publisher runnable

   ```
   class ZMQPublisherRunnable() extends Runnable {

    override def run() {
      val ZMQcontext = ZMQ.context(1)
      val publisher = ZMQcontext.socket(ZMQ.PUB)
      var count = 0

      publisher.connect(s"tcp://127.0.0.1:16666")

      while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) {
        try {
          println(s"PUBLISHER -> $count")
          publisher.send(s"PUBLISHER -> $count")
          count += 1
          Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
        catch {
          case e: Exception =>
          println(e.getMessage)
          publisher.disconnect(s"tcp://127.0.0.1:16666")
          ZMQcontext.close()
        }
      }
    }
   }
   ```
2. I have a Subscriber Runnable:

   ```
   class ZMQSubscriberRunnable1() extends Runnable {

     override def run() {

       println("STARTING SUBSCRIBER")

       val ZMQcontext = ZMQ.context(1)
       val subscriber = ZMQcontext.socket(ZMQ.SUB)
       subscriber.subscribe("".getBytes)

      subscriber.bind(s"tcp://127.0.0.1:16666")

       while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) {
         try {
           println("waiting")
           val mesg = new String(subscriber.recv(0))
           println(s"SUBSCRIBER -> $mesg")
         }
         catch {
           case e: Exception =>
             println(e.getMessage)
             subscriber.unbind("tcp://127.0.0.1:16666")
             subscriber.close()
             ZMQcontext.close()
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. My main code looks like this:

   ```
   object Application extends App {
     val zmqPUB = new ZMQPublisherRunnable
     val zmqThreadPUB = new Thread(zmqPUB, "MY_PUB")

     zmqThreadPUB.setDaemon(true)
     zmqThreadPUB.start()

     val zmqRunnable = new ZMQSubscriberRunnable1
     val zmqThread = new Thread(zmqRunnable, "MY_TEST")

     zmqThread.setDaemon(true)
     zmqThread.start()

     Thread.sleep(10000)

     zmqThread.interrupt()
     zmqThread.join()

     Thread.sleep(2000)

     val zmqRunnable_2 = new ZMQSubscriberRunnable1
     val zmqThread_2 = new Thread(zmqRunnable_2, "MY_TEST_2")

     zmqThread_2.setDaemon(true)
     zmqThread_2.start()

     Thread.sleep(10000)

     zmqThread_2.interrupt()
     zmqThread_2.join()
   }
   ```

The first time I start the Subscriber, I'm able to receive all messages:

```
STARTING SUBSCRIBER
PUBLISHER -> 0
waiting
PUBLISHER -> 1
SUBSCRIBER -> PUBLISHER -> 1
waiting
PUBLISHER -> 2
SUBSCRIBER -> PUBLISHER -> 2
waiting
PUBLISHER -> 3
SUBSCRIBER -> PUBLISHER -> 3
waiting
...
```

Once I interrupt the Thread and start a new one from the same Runnable, I'm not able to read messages anymore. It is waiting forever

```
STARTING SUBSCRIBER
waiting
PUBLISHER -> 13
PUBLISHER -> 14
PUBLISHER -> 15
PUBLISHER -> 16
PUBLISHER -> 17
...
```

Any insights about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Just adding a note: What I'm actually looking for is how can I close the ZMQ socket properly in a Thread.interrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JeroMQ` is not `Thread.interrupt` safe.

To work around it you have to stop the `ZMQContext` before you call the `Thread.interrupt`

1. Instantiate the `ZMQContext` outside the `Runnable`
2. Pass the `ZMQContext` as an argument to the `ZMQ Runnable` (You can also use it is a global variable)
3. Call `zmqContext.term()`
4. Call `zmqSubThread.interrupt()`
5. Call `zmqSubThread.join()`

For more details take a look at: https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/issues/116

My subscriber Runnable looks like:

```
class ZMQSubscriberRunnable(zmqContext:ZMQ.Context, port: Int, ip: String, topic: String) extends Runnable {

  override def run() {

    var contextTerminated = false
    val subscriber = zmqContext.socket(ZMQ.SUB)
    subscriber.subscribe(topic.getBytes)

    subscriber.bind(s"tcp://$ip:$port")

    while (!contextTerminated && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) {
      try {
        println(new String(subscriber.recv(0)))
      }
      catch {
        case e: ZMQException if e.getErrorCode == ZMQ.Error.ETERM.getCode =>
          contextTerminated = true
          subscriber.close()
        case e: Exception =>
          zmqContext.term()
          subscriber.close()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To interrupt the Thread:

```
zmqContext.term()
zmqSubThread.interrupt()
zmqSubThread.join()
```